# test passed in chai's assertion to expect an Error provided with empty string

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm newbee to chai and js testing.

I was testing a function that would filter a list of json with specific `type`. In this case, it should raise an error because no json contains a field `type` with value `abc`. The error message should be: `No matched module found when filtered with Type abc, JSON is null.`

```js
        it("should get no module, since no abc", ()=>
            expect(ModuleProcess.filterTypeModules.bind(ModuleProcess, "abc", mockFilterTypeLists.fullType)).to.throw(Error, " ")
        )
```

However, I found that when the expected thrown Error's message is **empty string** `""` or **one space** `" "`. The test can still pass. Is this normal? Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

The second argument in `.throw` is not the expected error message, but the message that chai reports if the expectation does not pass (I know, they called it just *message*).

To assert that the error thrown has a specific message, use the `.with.property` syntax.

```js
expect(ModuleProcess.filterTypeModules.bind(ModuleProcess, "abc", mockFilterTypeLists.fullType))
  .to.throw(Error).with.property("message", "No matched module found when filtered with Type abc, JSON is null.");
```